# How can I remotely connect to my MS SQL Server DB which is being hosted on a Windows Host?

Tags: sql-server, remote-access, remote-desktop, ado.net-entity-data-model, windows-hosting

I just created my Microsoft SQL Server Database on my own laptop and then made a backup file of it.

Then inside my **Windows Host** (Which I've bought from 1and1) I uploaded the .back file and then imported it to the newly made database.

Up to here everything was good. But when I try to connect to my database from my Visual Studio's ADO.NET Entity Data Model Wizard's Connection Settings window I get the following error:

[image: The error message]

I searched a lot online but unfortunately all solutions were for Windows Server or Local Computers While my Database is stored on a **Windows host**.

My connection settings can be seen in the image below:

[image: Connection Settings]

> I also called 1and1 support to ask whether my database's remote port is open or not, but the client couldn't get what I mean.

Comment: try using the IP address and not the DNS name.

Comment: First check your instance name you entered correctly or not? If yes, Open SQL Server Configuration Manager, choose <your SQL Server instance> protocols on the left and make sure that TCP/IP protocol is enabled (on the right). If you have a named instance (other than MSSQLSERVER and SQLEXPRESS) then double check that SQL Browser service is running as well.